# Creating a two-step sign up exactly like on Twitter [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, session, cookies, twitter

Uh, so I've been battling with this over many days already. So my goal is to create a registration form just like twitter has (A universal form on every page when filled, redirects to /signup page with the complete form, **retaining the submitted values**.)

Currently, I have the universal, short form on my public_controller and the full form in /signup that's part of users_controller.

I've tried rendering after filling the form, but I don't think that's the answer as the forms are on different controllers. I've also tried to do it with sessions and cookies, but with no luck.

Some code that is relevant, stripped of excess values:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => { :controller => 'users', :action => 'create' }) do |f| %>
<input name="user[name] />
<input name="user[email] />
<input name="user[password]" />
```

So I have three values in my universal signup form, :name, :email and :password. The final form will have one more value, :username.

My def new and def create of users_controller are honestly just empty now because I've been trying so many different things and I'm not sure what to put on them anymore.

Big thanks for all help, any directions are hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the vars from the first form to the second form:

```
 def controller_first_method
   @name     = params['name']
   @email    = params['email']
   @password = params['password'] <-- hash this before!!
 end
```

And in the second form:

```
= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @name
```

You can also try serializing the data:

https://github.com/mrbrdo/serialize-rails

Comment: Do the views with the forms have to be on the same controller with this, or does it not matter? This sounds like the logical way to do it, but I've tried everything and haven't got it to work so far.